# django - form field will not update without server reset... instantiating a class again

Tags: python, django

I have a form that is collecting data from a model. The problem is if I update information in the model/DB it will not show in the form until the server is restarted.

forms.py

```
class RecordForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
  type_choices = []
  choices = Domain.objects.all()
  for choice in choices:
    type_choices.append( (choice.id, choice.name) )
  domain = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=type_choices)
  type = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=Record.type_choices)
  content = forms.CharField()
  ttl = forms.CharField()
  comment = forms.CharField()
```

I am pulling data from the Domain model. On the website I have a page to enter the Domain information. Then there is another page where it will list those domains in a drop box. However, if you add or delete anything it will not show in the dropbox until you restart the server. My guess is that django only calls the form class once. Is there a way to make sure it reruns the class code when creating a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class RecordForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    domain = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[])
    type = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=...)
    content = forms.CharField()
    ttl = forms.CharField()
    comment = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['type'].choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Domain.objects.all()]
```

Comment: I have to disagree with the downvoting. Firstly, your comment on the other answer no more explains the problem then my code above - you've just verabalised what I've written. Furthermore, downvotes are to be reserved for `whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.` of which the above is none. While @Brandon's answer is probably the better of the two, a correct answer doesn't deserve a downvote

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. There's no difference in our answers; we even used a list comprehension :) Downvotes should be reserved for answers with errors or that are not good practice, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the `Domain` objects each time you instantiate a `RecordForm` by doing an override of the `__init__` for the model form.

```
class RecordForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.type_choices = [(choice.id, choice.name,) for choice in \
            Domain.objects.all()]

    domain = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=self.type_choices)
    ...
```

Comment: solid answer, the differnece is between setting the value of an attribute field when the class is defined and when a new instance is created.

Comment: In this case, setting choices equal to the instance variable, or defining the field and setting the choices accomplishes the same result.

Comment: I was having trouble with django complaining about self not being defined. I went with a slight variation of Timmy's solution and that seems to work. Thank you.